# Error downloading Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno

I know there are already a lot of tutorials regarding errors on Eclipse but here, I tried putting on javaw on the eclipse folder, created PATH on environment variables, reinstalled JRE and Eclipse.. but still I've got this error. What else should I do regarding with this?

[image]

Here's my PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin

And here's my eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: Show us your PATH variable and also the contents of the `eclipse.ini` file found in the eclipse's root directory.

Comment: Did you define your `JAVA_HOME` variable?  Show us your `PATH`.

Comment: @GeorgeD I've already put my eclipse. ini. I'm sorry for my late reply.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've already put on my path

Answer (score 0):

> Java SE 8u45
>   This release includes important security fixes. Oracle strongly recommends that all Java SE 8 users upgrade to this release

You have to download java jre and install it to the location specified by the error. [Java SE Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install Oracle JDK
2. Set java home. Follow Stage 2. [Link for manual](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows)